# the modifier public is not valid for this item

Tags: c#

I am getting error

> the modifier public is not valid for this item

this my code, please help me.

```
    using System;
    using System.Configuration;
    using System.Data;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Web;
    using System.Web.Security;
    using System.Web.UI;
    using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
    using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
    using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
    using System.Xml.Linq;
    public partial class First : System.Web.UI.Page,test 
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Label1.Text = test1("Hi", 1).ToString();
        }

    }
    public class Base
    {
        public int test1(int x)
        {
            return x;
        }
        public string test1(string x)
        {
            return x;
        }
        public string test1(string x, int y)
        {
            return x + y;
        }
    }
    public interface test
    {
        public int test1(int x);
        public string test1(string x);
        public string test1(string x, int y);
    }
```

Thanks,
Pradeep

Comment: The next time, please indicate on what line the error was reported.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Your interface declaration should look like this:

```
public interface test
{
    int test1(int x);
    string test1(string x);
    string test1(string x, int y);
}
```

Access modifiers are not valid on [interface declarations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173156.aspx):

> Interfaces consist of methods,
>   properties, events, indexers, or any
>   combination of those four member
>   types. An interface cannot contain
>   constants, fields, operators, instance
>   constructors, destructors, or types.
>   It cannot contain static members.
>   Interfaces members are automatically
>   public, and they cannot include any
>   access modifiers.

Comment: That error vanished but i am getting other error "'First' does not implement interface member 'interface.test.test1(int)'"

Comment: Read Hans's answer. It's because "First" doesn't contain the test1 functions, "Base" does and it is never inherited in any way.

Comment: i want to implement multiple inheritance using interface, please help me.

Answer (score 3):

Omit the "public" keyword from your interface method declarations.  That's not valid, interfaces always have public accessibility.

Defining these methods in the Base class isn't good enough either.  Either let the Base class inherit "test" or move the methods to First.

Declaring the Page_Load event handler protected is fishy too, it ought to be private since overriding it isn't possible and calling it directly from a class derived from First would normally be a mistake.