# The modifier 'public' is not valid for this item

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services

```
namespace WcfService1
{
    // NOTE: You can use the "Rename" command on the "Refactor" menu to change the interface name "IService1" in both code and config file together.
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface HelloWorldService
    {
        [OperationContract]
        [WebGet(UriTemplate = "")]

        public string HelloWorld() //here
        {
            return "Hello world!";
        }
    }
}
```

I get this error:

```
Error   1   The modifier 'public' is not valid for this item
```

This is what I have in my svc.cs file

```
public class Service1 : HelloWorldService
{
    public string HelloWorld()
    {
        return string.Format("Hello World!");
    }
}
```

This is actually from a tutorial from my uni:

Unlike last week, where we created interfaces for our services first, we are simply going to create WCF service objects in this first example. This is to save on time within the tutorial. Best practice means that we should be creating interfaces for all our services, which relates to the defined service contract. First of all create a new project within Visual Studio 2008 (remember to add the System.ServiceModel and System.ServiceModel.Web references, and the using declaration for both of these namespaces), and add the following class definition:

```
[ServiceContract]
public class HelloWorldService
{
[OperationContract]
[WebGet(UriTemplate="")]
public string HelloWorld()
{
return "Hello world!";
}
}
```

You should be familiar with the basic structure of this WCF service from last week’s tutorial. The difference lies in the extra attribute we have added to the method:
[WebGet(UriTemplate="")]
This attribute states that the service receives HTTP GET messages (the WebGet part), and that the rest of the URL is not relevant to the service end point (this will become clearer after the later examples). To host this service, we require the following main application:

Comment: possible duplicate of [the modifier public is not valid for this item](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3652717/the-modifier-public-is-not-valid-for-this-item)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Members on an `interface` declaration can't have an access modifier.  They implicitly have the same accessibility as the containing `interface`.  If you can access an interface, you can access all it's members

Comment: True.  I'd also add that you won't be able to define the method implementation in the interface.  That's not what interfaces are for!  You probably need to just remove the implementation there.  In other cases, it might make sense to change it to an abstract class or a class so you can provide an implementation.

Comment: how do I get what im trying to do I have this tutorial and it says to do this but its not working?

Comment: @Garrith if the tutorial says that you need to put `public` on `HelloWorld` in the `interface` definition then it's wrong unfortunately.  Just remove the `public` there and you should be good to go

Answer (score 3):

You can't specify scope or method bodies in an interface. Try this:

```
namespace WcfService1
{
    // NOTE: You can use the "Rename" command on the "Refactor" menu to change the interface name "IService1" in both code and config file together.
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface HelloWorldService
    {
        [OperationContract]
        [WebGet(UriTemplate = "")]

        string HelloWorld();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation:

> Interfaces declared directly within a namespace can be declared as
>   public or internal and, just like classes and structs, interfaces
>   default to internal access. Interface members **are always public**
>   because the **purpose of an interface is to enable other types to access
>   a class or struct**. No access modifiers can be applied to interface
>   members.

Source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173121%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can't declare accessibility on C# interfaces.  Nor can your interface methods have an implementation.